# Restart a windows service at specific time

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

i have created a service which executes an exe at certain time in background. I want to set a timer in such a way that the service executes the exe everyday at the same time.. how can that be done..??? Here is code I am writing in my service class:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    string time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
    Process p = new Process();

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\windows\ccm\ccmeval.exe");

        if (time == "6:55 PM")
        {
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            base.Stop();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()  { }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the Windows Task Scheduler instead of a service that... schedules... a task?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to run each task at 6:30 AM everyday

```
        var dtTimeToStartAt = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(30);
        dtTimeToStartAt = DateTime.Now > dtTimeToStartAt ? dtTimeToStartAt.AddDays(1) : dtTimeToStartAt;

        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x => YourCallbackMethod(), new object() /*not much use*/,
                                           dtTimeToStartAt.Subtract(DateTime.Now), new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0));
```

Comment: While a version of that will probably work, it's still like using a screwdriver to drive in a nail. Use the right tool for the job which in this case is the Windows Task Scheduler (without any further explanation from the OP of why it's not suitable).

Comment: i don't want to use the task scheduler. i want the code to be in such a way that it restarts the service at certain time .

Comment: you want to trigger a child thread from a parent process, which has to run all the time (its a win job). Best is what @J.Steen has advised.